# Rendering HTML cards via JavaScript problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, rendering

So basically what's the idea of my code: user inputs image URL, price, and description and click's
'create card' and then it should create a card.

All products that user create are saved in the 'productsArr' array;

After the user click's create card it should render HTML from the 'productsArr' array and display all the cards, but for some reason, it only creates a single card and then copies's it into HTML?

May someone please tell me what's wrong with my JS code?

PS sorry for my English

```js
let productsArr = [];

let product = {
    image: null,
    price: null,
    description: null,
    id: null
}

function getInfo() {
    product.image = document.getElementById("image").value;
    product.price = document.getElementById("price").value;
    product.description = document.getElementById("description").value;
    product.id = document.getElementById("id").value;
}

function render() {
    let arr = productsArr;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        let str = '';
        str = ' <div class="item_body" data-id="i">\n' +
            '            <img id="img" src="' + arr[i].image + '" alt="#">\n' +
            '            <div class="description">' + arr[i].description + '</div>\n' +
            '            <div class="price">' + arr[i].price + '</div>\n' +
            '            <input type="button" value="В коризну">' +
            '       </div>'
        document.getElementById('all_products').innerHTML += str;
        arr = [];
    }
}

function pushIt() {
    getInfo();
    productsArr.push(product);
    render(productsArr);
    product = {
        image: null,
        price: null,
        description: null,
        id: null
    }
}

function sortByPrice() {
    productsArr.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(a.price) - parseFloat(b.price));
}

console.log(productsArr)
```

```css
.container {
    max-width: 2000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: flex;
}

.form {
    height: 420px;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 50px;
    background: #73AFBA;
    border-radius: 10%;
}
label {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.products-section {
    width: 70%;
}
.products-section-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.products {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 10px 0;
}
.item_body {
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    border: #1C2E3D solid 1px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
.item_body img {
    max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="form">
        <label>
            <p>Image</p>
            <input id="image" type="text" name="image">
            <p>Price</p>
            <input id="price" type="text" name="price">
            <p>Description</p>
            <input id="description" type="text" name="description">
            <p>Id</p>
            <input id="id" type="text" name="id">
            <input type="submit" value="Create card" onclick="pushIt()">
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="products-section">
        <div class="products-section-header">
            <input type="button" name="sortByPrice" value="Sort by price" onclick="sortByPrice()">
        </div>
        <div class="products" id='all_products'></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are pushing the products in the `productsArr`. So instead of passing the `productsArr` to `render` function pass the current product to render function.
In this way, you don't need to use the `for` loop in the `render` function and you can use the `productsArr` for future use as well.

So your function will look like:

```
function pushIt() {
    getInfo();
    productsArr.push(product);
    render(product);
    product = {
        image: null,
        price: null,
        description: null,
        id: null
    }
}
```

And your `render` function will become:

```
function render(product) {
        let str = '';
        str = ' <div class="item_body" data-id="i">\n' +
            '            <img id="img" src="' + product.image + '" alt="#">\n' +
            '            <div class="description">' + product.description + '</div>\n' +
            '            <div class="price">' + product.price + '</div>\n' +
            '            <input type="button" value="В коризну">' +
            '       </div>'
        document.getElementById('all_products').innerHTML += str;
}
```

Comment: yea, but i want to save the array, so in the future i can sort them etc.